# Multi-byte characters and tr command

Tags: ruby, string, multibyte

I am trying to convert some single-byte characters into multi-byte characters using `tr`.

When I have just one character to convert, conversion works:

```
"\\".tr('\\', '＼')
# => "＼"
```

but if I add some more characters, the characters are not detected:

```
"\\".tr("\\¥'", "＼￥’")
# => "\\"
```

Why is that, and how can I convert multi-byte characters?

I am using Ruby 2.3.3. In addition, I get:

```
"\\".encoding #=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
"\\¥'".encoding #=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
"＼￥’".encoding #=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

Is this Ruby's bug?

Comment: Are you sure you're in UTF-8 mode?

Comment: Yes. I am using Ruby 2.3.3. In addition, ```"\\".encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
irb(main):007:0> "\\¥'".encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
irb(main):008:0> "＼￥’".encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>```

Comment: This could be a bug in `tr`, so you might want to investigate with the Ruby team. It looks like it works if you move the backslash character to the end of the set in `tr` so perhaps something in the internal implementaton is confused by it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A literal backslash must come last. From the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-tr): (emphasis added)

> The backslash character `\` can be used to escape `^` or `-` and **is otherwise ignored unless it appears at the end** of a range or the end of the `from_str` or `to_str`:

```
"\\abc".tr("\\abc", "/def") #=> "\\/de"
```

is equivalent to:

```
"\\abc".tr("abc", "/def") #=> "\\/de"
```

Versus:

```
"\\abc".tr("abc\\", "def/") #=> "/def"
```